# Water damaged Iphone 5S

Tags: hardware, iphone, damage

I have an IPhone 5S that I dropped and rolled into a puddle. Although I picked it up quickly and left it in rice all night the screen turned red (the screen isn't broken). I did some research and they said it might be water damaged. I checked the detection sticker by the sim card and it was white, but I know that there are two other indicators on the inside of the phone. I have to replace it and I'd rather not tell them that my phone fell into water because I'm worried they might not do it. My question is will apple open up my phone to check the sensors on the inside or do they just replace your phone without opening it.

Comment: It's clearly water damaged, and you'll need to accept responsibility.

Comment: I have heard but not yet experienced that if you go to an apple store and tell them truthfully what happened and ask if there is anything they can do like clean the contacts just to be safe, they have been known to replace it for free.

Comment: Can't post as answer, FWIW you can see at least one of the water sensors externally through the headphone jack. [Apple settled a lawsuit about overzealous enforcement their their water damage policy](http://appleinsider.com/articles/13/05/28/apple-to-pay-53m-in-iphone-ipod-liquid-sensor-lawsuit-settlement), last time I worked in Apple store only actual liquid or corrosion would void an Applecare+ plan. The provided answer below does a good job bringing up the oow replacement program but the phone must not be Beyond Economic Repair (BER) meaning it must be in one piece and able to be refurbed.

Answer (score 3):

My 4s went through the washing machine. It was totally wrecked. And, yes, the screen turned fluorescent Peptobismal pink. Because of lawsuits in Australia showing that the water sensor can be turned pink by humidity, Apple now allows repair/replacements for water damaged items. My memory is that it cost me $200 bucks to be given a new 32GB 4s under their Out of Warranty Replacement program. You can find the specifics of your situation and bring them with you in case the Genius you get is unfamiliar with their OWR policies: https://www.apple.com/legal/sales-support/terms/iphonears/outofwarranty.html